# Pro-rata volumes between a start time and an end time

Tags: oracle

Simplified, I have table like so:

```
start_date           end_date             units
06/03/2014 14:00:00  06/03/2014 15:30:00  300
```

What I want and have been trying to do is find out the duration (end_date - start_date). Split this into half hour intervals and then divide the units equally between these intervals.

In this case, the duration is 90 minutes, 3 half hour intervals, meaning 100 units in each interval.

From this I want to create something along these lines:

```
interval_date        units
06/03/2014 14:00:00  100
06/03/2014 14:30:00  100
06/03/2014 15:00:00  100
```

I have got this to work, but it involved numerous nesting of sub-queries (probably could clean it up a bit to use less). It also involved hard-coding columns for the interval, rather than one column to hold different intervals. For example, it looked like this:

```
id  d0000  ...  d1400  d1430  d1500  d1530  d1600 ... d2330
1   0           100    100    100    0      0         0
```

And for that reason it wasn't very flexible in the case that I wanted to change the interval duration (15 mins, 1 hour etc).

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if the duration is not divisible by 30 minutes.

Comment: Are the intervals fix? As you have given 5 different intervals in your example.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger They would be rounded up, so in the example above, if end date was 15:15, the result would remain the same.

Comment: @San I have edited my question to hopefully make it a bit more clear. In my attempt, I hard coded 48 columns (to deal with the 30 minute intervals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution covers *any* amount of rows (other answers will cover only one or have performance problems for many rows).

That's what I tried:

```
with yourTable as (select 1 id,
                          to_date('06/03/2014 14:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date,
                          to_date('06/03/2014 15:30:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') end_date,
                          300 units
                   from dual
                   union all
                   select 2 id,
                          to_date('05/03/2014 12:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date,
                          to_date('06/03/2014 23:30:15','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') end_date,
                          1000 units
                   from dual),
     setting as (select 1/24/2 /*every half an hour*/ interval from dual),
     borders as (select /* +materialize */ min(start_date) - 1 mindate,max(end_date) + 1 maxdate from yourTable),
     periods as (select /* +materialize */
                        mindate + interval*level period_start,
                        mindate + interval*(level + 1) - 1/24/60/60 /* - 1 sec */ period_end
                 from borders,setting
                 connect by level <= (maxdate - mindate)/interval)
select id,
       units,
       units/count(*) over (partition by id)
from periods p, yourTable y
where y.start_date between p.period_start and p.period_end
   or p.period_start between y.start_date and y.end_date;
```

where

1. `yourTable` should be just replaced with your table
2. `setting` I used as variable for setting up period, use `1/24` for hour or `1/24/4` for 15 minutes
3. `borders` is a variable with max and min dates of periods bulk
4. `periods` is a bulk of all needed periods
5. and finally the query which finds all the intersections of all calculated periods and periods in `yourTable`

For your example it returns 4 rows because 15:30 is a new period logically (15:29:59 will work as the end of the previous period). But I think you can handle this issue on your own: it requires additional information about your business logic.

Note that hint `/* +materialize */` is really important because without it Oracle Analyzer likes to "open" the subqueries with `connect by level` which makes it ubelievably not performant.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
with t as (
select to_date('06/03/2014 14:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:mi:ss') start_time,
       to_date('06/03/2014 15:10:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:mi:ss') end_time,
       300 units
  from dual
)
select start_time + (rownum - 1) / 48 start_interval,
       units / ceil((end_time - start_time) * 48) units
  from t
  where start_date <> end_date
connect by level <= ceil((end_time - start_time) * 48);

START_INTERVAL             UNITS
--------------             ----------
06.03.2014 14:00:00        100
06.03.2014 14:30:00        100
06.03.2014 15:00:00        100
```

**UPDATE**: Added `WHERE` condition to avoid divide by zero if `start_date` equals to `end_date`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Oracle 11gR2, you can use recursive CTE.

```
with x(start_date, end_date, units) as (
  --select all the records and units per half an hour.
  select start_date, end_date, units/((end_date - start_date)*48)
  from myt
  union all
  --iteratively add 30 minutes to start_date till it stays less than end_date
  select start_date + interval '30' minute, end_date, units
  from x
  where start_date + interval '30' minute < end_date
  )
select start_date, units
from x
order by 1;
```

Schema:

```
create table myt(
  start_date date,
  end_date   date,
  units      number
  );

insert into myt values(to_date('06/03/2014 14:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
                       to_date('06/03/2014 15:30:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
                       300
                       );

insert into myt values(to_date('06/04/2014 11:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
                       to_date('06/04/2014 15:30:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
                       300
                       );
```

Output:

```
START_DATE                      UNITS
-------------------------- ----------
03-JUN-2014 14:00:00              100
03-JUN-2014 14:30:00              100
03-JUN-2014 15:00:00              100
04-JUN-2014 11:00:00       33.3333333
04-JUN-2014 11:30:00       33.3333333
04-JUN-2014 12:00:00       33.3333333
04-JUN-2014 12:30:00       33.3333333
04-JUN-2014 13:00:00       33.3333333
04-JUN-2014 13:30:00       33.3333333
04-JUN-2014 14:00:00       33.3333333
04-JUN-2014 14:30:00       33.3333333
04-JUN-2014 15:00:00       33.3333333
```

Comment: Thanks for a great solution. Sorry I didn't specify which version I was using in the question. Unfortunately the production database is currently running on 10g. Hoping someone else gets good use out of this :)